# SQLiteDatabase delete involving sub query

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I am using SQLiteDatabase for a Java library, and I need to support a very low version of the Android API (v4), which doesn't ship with SQLite version that supports Foreign Keys.

Therefore in order to delete a top level piece of data and all it's "children", I need to delete these children before in such a manner to manually reproduce the same effect as the Foreign Key constraint `ON DELETE CASCADE`

What I'm trying to do is the following SQL with the delete api.

```
DELETE FROM childTable 
WHERE someFK IN (
    SELECT parent_id 
    FROM parentTable 
    WHERE someFlag = 1
)
```

The initial solution I came up with was to hard code the select query in my where clause as follows, however since the SQLiteDatabase api supports query's, execSQL etc, is this solution I used horribly wrong and dangerous to use ?
Workaround:

```
String[] whereArgs = {Integer.toString(1)};
this.database.delete(TABLE_CHILD_ONE, COL_ONE_FK_SESSION+" IN (SELECT "+COL_SESSION_ID+" FROM "+TABLE_SESSIONS+" WHERE "+COL_SESSION_DONE+"=?)", whereArgs);
this.database.delete(TABLE_CHILD_TWO, COL_TWO_FK_SESSION+" IN (SELECT "+COL_SESSION_ID+" FROM "+TABLE_SESSIONS+" WHERE "+COL_SESSION_DONE+"=?)", whereArgs);
this.database.delete(TABLE_CHILD_THREE, COL_THREE_FK_SESSION+" IN (SELECT "+COL_SESSION_ID+" FROM "+TABLE_SESSIONS+" WHERE "+COL_SESSION_DONE+"=?)", whereArgs);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create trigger for each table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_cascade AFTER DELETE ON parentTable
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM childTable child WHERE child.parent_id=OLD.id;
END;
```

Run it in transaction.

[More about triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)